# List doesn't show correctly in DIV element

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a div element which has these css attributes :

**HTML**

```
<div class="messageContainer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.messageContainer {
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-color: #F7F5F2;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

When putting this html portion inside the div element :

```
Please do the things respectively: 
<ol>
   <li>
      Create button control
   </li>
   <li>
      Assign it to the main user
   </li> 
   <li>
      Let me know what happened
   </li>
</ol>
```

**This is how it shows on the page:**  (Please look at the numbers)

[image: Screen Shot]

So the question is why this is happening?Why are the numbers are appearing outside of the div element.

**EDIT**

I used :

```
.messageContainer ol
{
    list-style-position:inside;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

which worked just fine but now this is what happened :

[image]

Comment: It's not doing that for me.  Which browser are you viewing this in?  It could be that this is caused by some CSS elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your CSS:

```
.messageContainer ol
{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```